# What is the correct ASP.NET Control event/method in which to add nested controls?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, asp.net-controls, createchildcontrols

What is the correct event/method in the ASP.NET life cycle to dynamically add Child Controls ?

My objective is to ensure that all the input controls on a User Control have the correct associated Validator and Label controls, based on configuration from an external file.

It seems like the correct place should be either  `OnInit(EventArgs e)` or `CreateChildControls()`.  Both of them are behaving a little bit unexpected, and rather than try to debug each of them, I figured I'd first ask you guys which one (or other) to use.

Comment: Care to explain the issues your having?

Comment: @asawyer, I've been moving stuff around trying to figure it out.  So far, I've gotten an `OutOfMemoryException` (making me think there I was causing an infinite loop), a "Multiple controls with the same ID 'dynamicallyAddedRequiredFieldValdiator' were found" (making me think I put it somewhere that caused the routine to be called twice), a "Collection was modified, enumeration may not execute" error and a "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.".

Comment: Is this a custom server control, or a web user control (ASCX)?

Comment: @James, it's a web user control, However, if there is a difference with respect to this distinction please specify, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its OnInit, and you need to do it on first load **and** on post back.

Comment: So, I call the routine ALWAYS OnInit, and also ALWAYS on PostBack ?  Or do I call it from OnInit and make sure it is either (a) the first load or (b) a postback.  Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: If you put your code in `OnInit`, it will be called every time the page is posted - first, last, and every postback in between.

Comment: @smartcaveman - Create your control in OnInit, and do it on every call, eg don't check for postback.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Web User Control (ASCX) create the dynamic controls during `OnInit`. By creating them during `OnInit` they will be created on the first page load and on every postback.

The `CreateChildControls` method is typically used for rendering in custom server controls.